# Remove CALayers from Parent UIView

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

There are several questions like this floating around, but no answer that works.

I'm adding new CALayers to a UIView like so:

```
    func placeNewPicture() {
        let newPic = CALayer()
        newPic.contents = self.pictureDragging.contents
        newPic.frame = CGRect(x: pictureScreenFrame.origin.x - pictureScreenFrame.width/2, y: pictureScreenFrame.origin.y - pictureScreenFrame.height/2, width: pictureScreenFrame.width, height: pictureScreenFrame.height)
        self.drawingView.layer.addSublayer(newPic)
    }
```

and trying to remove them with:

```
    func deleteDrawing() {

        for layer in self.drawingView.layer.sublayers {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
```

This successfully removes the images, but the app crashes the next time the screen is touched, with a call to main but nothing printed in the debugger. There are several situations like this out there, where apps will crash a short time after removing sublayers.

What is the correct way to remove CALayers from their parent View?

Comment: paste crash logs. removing CALayers won't cause crash, unless some methods or objects tried to access the deallocated layers again.

Comment: If @Leo's answer doesn't solve the issue, you're probably crashing because the array you're iterating through is getting modified as you remove layers. Iterate through the layers in reverse, and this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the error is you delete all sublayers,not the ones you added.
keep a property to save the sublayers you added

```
    var layerArray = NSMutableArray()
```

Then try

```
func placeNewPicture() {
    let newPic = CALayer()
    newPic.contents = self.pictureDragging.contents
    newPic.frame = CGRect(x: pictureScreenFrame.origin.x - pictureScreenFrame.width/2, y: pictureScreenFrame.origin.y - pictureScreenFrame.height/2, width: pictureScreenFrame.width, height: pictureScreenFrame.height)
    layerArray.addObject(newPic)
    self.drawingView.layer.addSublayer(newPic)
}
func deleteDrawing() {

    for layer in self.drawingView.layer.sublayers {
        if(layerArray.containsObject(layer)){
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            layerArray.removeObject(layer)
        }
    }
}
```

Update with **Leo Dabus** suggest,you can also just set a name of layer.

```
newPic.name = "1234"
```

Then check

```
func deleteDrawing() {

    for layer in self.drawingView.layer.sublayers {
        if(layer.name == "1234"){
            layerArray.removeObject(layer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Leo, this is working great. I have been testing for about 10 minutes now and nothing has crashed so far.

Comment: You could just set a name for the layers https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/name

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for you suggest,I update my answer with your suggest

Comment: Leo, your solution is great, but the update deleteDrawing should be if(layer.name == "1234") {layer.removeFromSuperlayer() }

Comment: only thing that stops that infamous crash